# kill a batch file that is stuck from another cmd box

Tags: batch-file

Hope I'm in the right place here, wasn't sure where to post and this seemed the most likely

I use a cmd box to run a serial flasher program for repairing wifi boards, the way it works is this.
open a command prompt and change to the working directory
enter the command

```
sfh_DM36x.exe -nandflash -v -p "COM3"
```

this starts the flashing program, however, due to the way it works, the program when finishing the first time just loops with bootme bootme, this is normal behavior.
Normally I just hit `CTRL+C` and exit the batch file.
The same command is run again and this time the flashing process completes and you are returned to the `C:\` prompt.

Now you have the information here is what I am trying to achieve.

Launch a batch file that runs the runflash.bat, kill the runflash.bat and then run runflash.bat again.

So far I have gotten as far as this (start.bat)

```
start c:\users\jud\desktop\runflash.bat
timeout /t 5
```

This runs a new CMD prompt and opens the `runflash.bat`

I've then entered a timeout of 5 seconds (long enough for the first attempt to finish)

at this point, I wanted to kill the currently open CMD prompt and then execute `runflash.bat` again.

at this point I'm stumped, any attempt to kill the second CMD prompt just kills the original, I've looked at `taskkill` but the PID changes each time I run the script, as well as other suggestions I've come across during google searches, most just relate to killing batch files manually or killing a CMD prompt where a batch file has finished.

Can this be done, the idea is to pass the file out to users who aren't familiar with CMD prompt workings as an all in one solution.

Comment: It sounds as if you just want to start a batch file with a known WindowTitle or PID, then you can Start it, Timeout for a reasonable period, then TaskKill it using the known WindowTitle or PID, before looping back to invoking the file. Please search this site and take a look at the command help for further information. You can get help on almost any command by opening a Command Prompt window and typing its name followed by `/?` and pressing enter.

Comment: `start` can give the new process a defined window title and `taskkill` has a filter to look for a window title. Should be no big issue.

Answer (score 2):

Provide the new process with a unique title (see `start /?` - the first quoted parameter is set as a title). `Takskkill` can then identify and close the process with its title:

```
start "JudRunFlash" "c:\users\jud\desktop\runflash.bat"
timeout /t 5 >nul
taskkill /fi "WindowTitle eq JudRunFlash"
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the reply, I will give it a try later.

Comment: problem, the CMD.exe shows INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria.

Comment: and doesnt kill the JudRunFlash box.

Comment: it would appear that the looping BootMe message is causing the issue, If i break the BootMe loop then it works

Comment: I like to give a process the chance to properly terminate itself. But if it doesn't obey - force it to close with `tasklist /f ...`

Comment: Thanks Stephen for the help, ive finally solved it, here is the code I used

Comment: start "JudRun" "c:\users\jud\desktop\runflash.bat"
    timeout /t 7 >nul
     taskkill /im  sfh_dm36x.exe /f
taskkill /fi "WindowTitle eq JudRun"
timeout /t 2 >nul
start "JudRun" "c:\users\jud\desktop\runflash.bat"
timeout /t 40 >nul
taskkill /fi "WindowTitle eq JudRun"
echo. thats it all done.................
echo. this box will close in 6 seconds
timeout /t 7 >nul

Comment: i had to kill the SFH which is the serial flasher program in order to be able to close the working windows, i can now get it to run twice, just going to do some tidying of the code, out of interest can i have the runflash,bat windows auto minimise

Comment: its ok I found Start /min as the command, thanks again most appreciated